# Tallying unknown words across columns in Tableau (or from comma separated column)

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have an issue that I have been trying to solve for the better part of a week now. I have a large database (in Google sheets) representing casestudies. I have some columns with multiple categories listed (in this example 'species', 'genera', and 'morphologies'), and I want to be able to tally how many times each category occurs in the data set.

I use Tableau to visalise the data, and the final output will be a large publc tableau. I know I can do a "find" based on the specific string, but I'd like the dataset to be dynamic and be able to handle new data being added without having to update calculated fields? Is there a way of finding uniqe terms (either from a single column of comma separated values, or from multiple columns), and tallying them?

Things I have tried so far:

1 - A pivot table in Tableau. Works well, but messes with all the other data, since it repeats lines.
2 - A pivot table on its own data source in Tableau. Also works well, and avoids the problem of messing with the other data. However, now each figure is disconnected from the others so I can't do a large dashboard where everything is filtered by each other (ie filtering species and genera by country at the same time).
3 - An SQL query() in google sheets, which finds all unique terms and queries them, which can then be plotted in Tableau. Also works well, but similar problem of the data being disconnected from all the other terms in the dataset.

Any ideas of a field calculation that will find, list and tally unique terms in a single comma separated column (or across multiple columns), without changing the data structure?

I have placed a sample data set [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hB1zuxnCwQPVzGbVnGDjyhnvd8UTxJ5WfpJ8Rd0kIdQ/edit?usp=sharing) (google sheets), which is a smaller version of what I'm actually working on. In it I have marked comma separated columns in grey, and they're followed by a bunch of columns with the values split into columns. I only need to analyse either of those (ie either a calculation to separate comma separate values or from multiple columns).

I've also added a sample Tableau workbook [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hB1zuxnCwQPVzGbVnGDjyhnvd8UTxJ5WfpJ8Rd0kIdQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Interesting problem - could you simply add a column full of `1` values, then sum with them up in a single `IF` or `CASE` statement - e.g. `IF [Coral Species] LIKE "Stylophora pistillata" THEN SUM([Vales]) END` (this is not tested!)

Comment: Thanks @BenP - yeah there are certainly ways that I can use IF statements and FIND to search out specific terms, but ideally I would like to avoid having to build a 'static' query, in favour of something that is more dynamic. Ie imagine I add more species later on, then I would have to add more search terms to the IF statements. I was hoping there was a way to find unique values, and then tallying them!